# Clone content of repository/subfolder on server

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, clone, subdirectory

I have a git repo which has many folders and I have separate subdomains for them.

For example I have:

```
repo
├── folder1
├── folder2
└── folder3
```

Now `folder1`, `folder2` and `folder3` are subfolders but I have separate subdomains for them like.

Content inside `folder1` will need to go to `folder1.domain.com` and same is the case with other folders.

Is there anyway in git I can clone these subfolders in their subdomains and then able to pull whenever I change anything in actual repo.

**Note: I want this on server.**

[Here is another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of server to server cloning . As it's 1 time operation why  don't  you upload from client to sever . Clone entire repository in local. Now seperate it in 3 folders as par your need and push onto separate severs.

Comment: Its not a one time thing, you will have to pull whenever you make changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use|reference subdir inside Git-repo as usual URL
2. You can't split monorepo into set of nested repos inside wrapper-repo on server
3. You can't clone part of Git-repo into new repo (except [case there special conditions are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934))

## Resume

You must to read *a lot more* Git-docs in order (client-side):

- split current repo into the set of linked repos
- add appropriate remotes
- use Git subtree (**not** git submodules) for management of new collection (staring points [one](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree) and [two](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/the-power-of-git-subtree/) for dive into subtrees may help)